# Unable to Install ngx-bootstrap To template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-bootstrap, core-ui

Trying to install ngx-boostrap into a template for further enhancement but got stuck and not sure what needs to be done and if updating rxjs will suffice and what version? Need help on a way forward and how to proceed to resolve the error.

Appreciate any help

```
 While resolving: coreui-free-angular-admin-template@4.3.0
Found: rxjs@7.5.7
node_modules/rxjs
  rxjs@"~7.5.0" from the root project
  peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/core@15.2.9
  node_modules/@angular/core
    @angular/core@"^15.0.4" from the root project
    peer @angular/core@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0
    node_modules/ngx-bootstrap

     peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/forms@15.2.9
  node_modules/@angular/forms
    @angular/forms@"^15.0.4" from the root project
    peer @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0
    node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
      ngx-bootstrap@"*" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.6.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
  ngx-bootstrap@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: It seems that the nxg-bootstrap project is dead unfortunately. Probably thanks to Putin (the team behind it is from Ukraine).